# nested element FOR XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to create XML from SQL Server and I'm stuck with nested elements. I try different FOR XML parameters but still cannot get the correct results.

query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
Product.ID, Product.ProductName,
    (SELECT
    Images.ProductImage AS image
    FROM Images 
    WHERE Images.ProductID = Product.ID
    FOR XML PATH ('image_list'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
    )
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, ProductName FROM Product) Product
FOR XML PATH ('products'), ELEMENTS, root ('Root')
```

and I want get this XML like this:

```
<Root>
  <products>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ProductName>product 1</ProductName>
    <image_list>
      <image>picture1.jpg</image>
      <image>picture2.jpg</image>
      <image>picture3.jpg</image>
    </image_list>
  </products>
  <products>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ProductName>product 2</ProductName>
    <image_list>
      <image>picture1.jpg</image>
      <image>picture2.jpg</image>
    </image_list>
  </products>
</Root>
```

First part is OK, the image_list is a problem. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

I solved :) ..probably is good to post a qustion, after that brain starts to work :)

I add AS 'image_list' under subquery, remove ELEMENTS and PATH name. 
And that's it.

```
SELECT 
Product.ID, Product.ProductName,
    (SELECT
    Images.ProductImage AS image
    FROM Images 
    WHERE Images.ProductID = Product.ID
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ) 'image_list'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, ProductName FROM Product) Product
FOR XML PATH ('products'), ELEMENTS, root ('Root')
```

Results is:

```
<Root>
  <products>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ProductName>product 1 </ProductName>
    <image_list>
      <image>picture1.jpg</image>
      <image>picture2.jpg</image>
      <image>picture3.jpg</image>
    </image_list>
  </products>
  <products>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ProductName>product 2 </ProductName>
    <image_list>
      <image>picture1.jpg</image>
      <image>picture2.jpg</image>
    </image_list>
  </products>
</Root>
```

Comment: For everyone's enjoyment add some example output